# Why my "PURE JAVASCRIPT BASED" offline file is not supporting "onload" events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload, html-editor

I have a offline "htm" file on my PC which I use to test HTML codes. It is like a HTML editor. It compiles HTML codes. But I have a problem with it. It supports all kinds of CSS and JavaScript and also JavaScript Based Libraries like jQuery but does not support events like- `onload, $(document).ready()` I don't know why? I have tried many things about it but was able to do nothing.

So see the source code of my editor:

```
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowResult()
  {
    my_window = window.open("about:blank", "mywindow1");
    my_window.document.write(x);
    if(my_window.document.title=="")
    {
      my_window.document.title="No title was specified"
    }
  }
 </script>
 <body>
   <textarea style="height:400px;width:750px;overflow:auto;" onblur="x=this.value">
   </textarea><br />
   <button onclick="ShowResult()">see result!</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what mistake have I done? Why me file is not supporting "onload" events?

Comment: ...why not just write your html code in an actual html file and load it in a browser?

Comment: Is that something like WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: _"but does not support events like- `onload`, `$(document).ready()` I don't know why"_ - **What have you tried**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing the code within the context of a page that is already loaded.

Systems like jsfiddle handle this by dynamically generating a page and loading it into an iframe.

You'd need some sort of server-side scripting to do this. I'd advise installing a local webserver (i.e. Wampserver).

Comment: Well i think your answer may help. Please elaborate. What is this Wampserver and my pc does not have asp.net will Wampserver run on it. My OS is Windows XP Professional edition. Please tell me more on this topic. And thank you for you instant answer.

Comment: WAMPserver is basically a complete webserver you can install on Windows; it includes Apache (the webserver), MySQL (a database) and PHP (a server-side language).
There are many alternatives, and probably one that matches your preferred webserver, database and language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize x:

```
<html> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  x = ""; 
  function ShowResult() 
  { 
    my_window = window.open("about:blank", "mywindow1"); 
    my_window.document.write(x); 
    if(my_window.document.title=="") 
    { 
      my_window.document.title="No title was specified" 
    } 
  } 
 </script> 
 <body> 
   <textarea style="height:400px;width:750px;overflow:auto;" onblur="x=this.value"> 
   </textarea><br /> 
   <button onclick="ShowResult()">see result!</button> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I don't need to do that because I have already initialized "x" with the help of inline-javascript see this `<textarea style="height:400px;width:750px;overflow:auto;" onblur="x=this.value">` don't you know variable declared in a inline-javascript code is declared as a global variable. And suppose if you are saying correct then too it has no relation with the "onload" event. Right?

Comment: @InneedofHelp: What if the blur event hasn't yet fired? You then get an error, because `x` is undefined. With this addition, the code works for me.

Comment: One minute, read my question the editor is already working. There only one problem i.e. the "onload" event is not working. And what do you mean by blur event hasn't fired yet  (read next comment)

Comment: If you write or copy/paste something in the textarea you have to give the textarea focus. And when you will click the button the textarea will lose focus, that means it is not possible that the button is clicked and blur event is not fired, OK.

Comment: @InneedofHelp: If I click the button without clicking in the box at all (i.e, without firing "blur"), the page errors, since `x` is not defined.

Comment: JavaScript is too fast as you click on the button a blur event is fired and the command execution of the blur event will take place before the javascript associated with the button and my editor is working properly. I tried your suggestion too but then too I can't fire any "onload" event. And if we suppose that we have not fired the blur event in your code then also the result will show nothing.

Comment: "as you click on the button a blur event is fired" - not true. The blur event fires iff the textarea was already selected. "the result will show nothing" - This is what it should do. At present, _an exception is thrown_.

Comment: One minute, let me tell you exactly what actually happens. When the button is clicked the button receives focus and textarea being out of the button looses focus and that's what blur means when an elements loses focus. If the button will get focus the textarea will lose focus. Was there anything wrong in this comment? And I would like to move this discussion to chat. How to do that?

Comment: You don't have enough rep to use chat... _"textarea being out of the button looses focus"_ - there's your mistake. The textarea only _loses_ focus if it _had_ focus. When the page loads, it does _not_ have focus.

Comment: When you write or copy/paste something in the textarea it gains focus. And why will you press the button before writing anything? If we do not write anything then, what is the big deal in seeing a result `undefined` when it is really undefined. Am I wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12465/discussion-between-in-need-of-help-and-eric)